# Texture does not appear in OpenGl

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

`main Function`:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    _mesh1 = new Mesh("obj\\Earth_2K.obj", "obj\\Diffuse_2K_Earth.png");
    _mesh2 = new Mesh("obj\\Moon 2K.obj", "obj\\Diffuse_2K_Moon.png");
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    glutCreateWindow("Univers Drawing");
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);
    glutReshapeFunc(ChangeSize);
    glutIdleFunc(glIdle);
    SetupRC();
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Mesh class object declared in main function. Hand over the obj and texture files to this object to read the vertex, texel, and face values.

`Mesh class constructor`:

```cpp
    Mesh(char* obj, char* texture) {
        open(obj);
        loadTexture(texture, _textureIndex);
    }
```

In this code, the `Open` function is responsible for loading the obj file and creating a mesh. There's no problem so far. However, the problem occurs in the texture after that.

`loadTexture Fuction`:

```cpp
void Mesh::loadTexture(char* file, GLuint& texture_index) {
    glGenTextures(1, &texture_index);

    FILE* fp;
    fopen_s(&fp, file, "rb");
    if (!fp) {
        printf("ERROR : No %s.\n fail to bind %d\n", file, texture_index);
    }
    int width, height, channel;
    unsigned char *image = stbi_load_from_file(fp, &width, &height, &channel, 4);
    fclose(fp);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_index);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_COLOR, GL_MODULATE);
}
```

This function is responsible for setting up the textures. `texture_index` is a GLuint type variable declared in the Mesh class header file. `stbi_load_from_file` is the use of the stb_image library. It seems to me that there is no problem here. Because there is no problem when printing obj one by one.

`RenderScene Function`:

```cpp
void RenderScene(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // World Transfrom

    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();

    ///////////////////Drawing//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Figure0 Draw
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glutSolidSphere(10, 15, 15);
    glPopMatrix();

    // Figure1 Draw 
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glRotatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(Sphere1_degree, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glTranslatef(70.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);        
    _mesh1->drawSolid(_smoothing);
    glPopMatrix();


    // Figure2 Draw 
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glRotatef(-45.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glRotatef(Sphere2_degree, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glTranslatef(60.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);    
    _mesh2->drawSolid(_smoothing);
    glPopMatrix();
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

This function is the content of `glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);` in the main function. The code for this function represents how two objs rotate around a central circle. This is where I'm confused.

I think I should do `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _mesh1->_textureIndex);` but I don't know which code to do it in.

`drawSolid Function`:

```cpp
void Mesh::drawSolid(bool smoothing) {
    glPushMatrix();
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textureIndex);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    smoothing == true ? glEnable(GL_SMOOTH) : glEnable(GL_FLAT);
    for (auto f : _faces) {
        // get texture coord
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        if(!smoothing)
            glNormal3f(f->_normal.x(), f->_normal.y(), f->_normal.z());
        _textureCoords[f->_texelPos[0]];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            auto t = _textureCoords[f->_texelPos[i]];
            auto v = f->_vertices[i];
            glTexCoord2f((GLfloat)t->x(), (GLfloat)t->y());
            if (smoothing)
                glNormal3f(v->_normal.x(), v->_normal.y(), v->_normal.z());
            glVertex3f(v->x(), v->y(), v->z());
        }           
        glEnd();
    }
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

In this function, there is a variable called `smoothing`, which is just a role that determines how to proceed with the smoothing method. The important thing is that I definitely proceeded with `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textureIndex);` in this code, but the texture does not appear normally.

**the result of what I got it**

[image]

**obj printed one by one to debug the `loadTexture` function.**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use any OpenGL instruction before you have created an OpenGL context. The OpenGL context is created with the OpenGL window. So`_mesh1 = new Mesh(...)` needs to be called after creating the window with `glutCreateWindow`:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    glutCreateWindow("Univers Drawing");

    _mesh1 = new Mesh("obj\\Earth_2K.obj", "obj\\Diffuse_2K_Earth.png");
    _mesh2 = new Mesh("obj\\Moon 2K.obj", "obj\\Diffuse_2K_Moon.png");

    // [...]
}
```

---

You must set a white color in the `drawSolid` method before drawing the mesh:

```cpp
void Mesh::drawSolid(bool smoothing) {
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);  

    // [...]
}
```

Explanation:

When texturing is activated, by default the color of the texel is multiplied by the current color, because by default the texture environment mode (`GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE`) is `GL_MODULATE`. See [`glTexEnv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexEnv.xml).

This causes that the color of the texels of the texture is "mixed" by the last color which you have set by [`glColor4f`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml).

Set a "white" color before you render the texture, to solve your issue:

```cpp
glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```

Likewise you can change the environment mode to `GL_REPLACE`, instead:

```cpp
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
```

---

When lighting ([`GL_LIGHTING`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnable.xml)) is enabled, then the color which is associated, is taken from the material parameters  ([`glMaterial`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMaterial.xml)).

If you still want to use the current color attribute (which is set by [`glColor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml)), then you have to enable [`GL_COLOR_MATERIAL`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnable.xml)
and to set the color material parameters ([`glColorMaterial`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColorMaterial.xml)):

```cpp
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
```